# Error when insert Textfield into column Flutter

Tags: user-interface, flutter, dart

[image: I want to build Flutter UI like this]

This is my code

```
SafeArea(
  child: Scaffold(
    body: Container(
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[],
          ),
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
            children: <Widget>[
              Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Flexible(
                    child: Container(
                      width: 100,
                      child:
                          TextFormField(decoration: const InputDecoration()),
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
              Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Flexible(
                    child: Container(
                      width: 100,
                      child:
                          TextFormField(decoration: const InputDecoration()),
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
              Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Flexible(
                    child: Container(
                      width: 100,
                      child:
                          TextFormField(decoration: const InputDecoration()),
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              )
            ],
          )
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

But when I run that code it shows error like following

```
═══════ Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════
RenderBox was not laid out: RenderFlex#1b387 relayoutBoundary=up3 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
Failed assertion: line 1694 pos 12: 'hasSize'
The relevant error-causing widget was
    Row 
lib\GPA1.dart:24
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
```

I can't build my project. Can anyone help me??

I used flutter 1.17.0

I use my mobile device to preview this

I use Samsung Galaxy A5 2016

I use Flexible to wrap TextFormField but it shows the same error again.

Comment: why are using `column` widget when you are only trying to insert one textfield inside it, directly use `Container -> textfield` widget

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap Row Widget with Expanded widget.

```
SafeArea(
        child: Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[],
            ),
            Expanded( // added 
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Flexible(
                        child: Container(
                          width: 100,
                          child: TextFormField(
                              decoration: const InputDecoration()),
                        ),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                  Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Flexible(
                        child: Container(
                          width: 100,
                          child: TextFormField(
                              decoration: const InputDecoration()),
                        ),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                  Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Flexible(
                        child: Container(
                          width: 100,
                          child: TextFormField(
                              decoration: const InputDecoration()),
                        ),
                      )
                    ],
                  )
                ],
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ));
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should get rid of the "Flexible".

```
Row(
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
  children: <Widget>[
    Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(
          width: 100,
          child: TextFormField(decoration: const InputDecoration()),
        ),
      ],
    ),
    Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(
          width: 100,
          child: TextFormField(decoration: const InputDecoration()),
        ),
      ],
    ),
    Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(
          width: 100,
          child: TextFormField(decoration: const InputDecoration()),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ],
),
```

Answer (score 0):

This code will do the job.

```
 SafeArea(
    child: Scaffold(
  body: Container(
    margin: EdgeInsets.all(5),
    child: Column(
      mainAxisAlignment:
          MainAxisAlignment.start,
      children: <Widget>[
        Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(
                child: Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                        left: 5, right: 5),
                    child: TextFormField(
                        decoration:
                            const InputDecoration()))),
            Expanded(
                child: Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                        left: 5, right: 5),
                    child: TextFormField(
                        decoration:
                            const InputDecoration()))),
            Expanded(
                child: Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                        left: 5, right: 5),
                    child: TextFormField(
                        decoration:
                            const InputDecoration())))
          ],
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
));
```

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XeXB5.png)